# RandomForest algorithm in SparkR?

Tags: r, sparkr

I have implemented randomForest algorithm in R and trying to implement the same using sparkR (from Apache Spark 2.0.0).

But I found only linear model functions like glm() implementations in sparkR 
https://www.codementor.io/spark/tutorial/linear-models-apache-spark-1-5-uses-present-limitations

And Couldn't able to find any RandomForest (Decision Tree algorithm) examples. 
There is RandomForest in Spark's MLLib but cannot able to find the R bindings for MLLib also.

Kindly let me know, whether SparkR(2.0.0) supports RandomForest? else is it possible to connect SparkR with MLlib to use RandomForest?
If not how can we acheive this using SparkR?

Answer (score 1):

True, it's not available in SparkR as of now.
Possible option is to build random forest on distributed chunks of data and combine your trees later.
Anyways its all about randomness.

A good link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sparkr-dev/3N6LK7k4NB0

Comment: It has since become available: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/R/spark.randomForest.html